# error: cannot shadow already defined class `Error` after adding console_error_panic_hook::set_once();

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen, wasm-pack

Simply adding `console_error_panic_hook::set_once()` causes the error:

```
[WARN]: :-) origin crate has no README
[INFO]: Installing wasm-bindgen...
error: cannot shadow already defined class `Error`
Error: Running the wasm-bindgen CLI
Caused by: failed to execute `wasm-bindgen`: exited with exit code: 1
```

And yes, I do have my own `Error` struct, but why does using this function cause a "shadow" error?

The error only happens if I export the `Error` struct with `[wasm_bindgen]`.

The error occurs after running `wasm-pack build --target web`

## Reproduction

```
# cargo.toml
[package]
name = "testing"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "rlib"]

[dependencies]
console_error_panic_hook = "0.1.7"
wasm-bindgen = { version = "0.2.76" }
```

```rust
// lib.rs

use wasm_bindgen::prelude::wasm_bindgen;
// Adding this does not help:
// extern crate console_error_panic_hook;

#[wasm_bindgen] // Works if either this line is remove...
struct Error {}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn main() {
    console_error_panic_hook::set_once(); // ... or this one
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

## Versions

```
wasm-pack 0.10.2
cargo 1.58.0 (f01b232bc 2022-01-19)
rustc 1.58.1 (db9d1b20b 2022-01-20)
```

Comment: If I can provide additional information if required. Also if you think this is a bug, let me know and I'll will open an issue on... well either wasm_bindgen or the panic hook, not sure yet what is failing.

Comment: The `console_error_panic_hook` crate [defines its own `Error` type binding](https://github.com/rustwasm/console_error_panic_hook/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L88). I wouldn't think that multiple bindings to the same type would be a problem, but I'm also not that familiar with `wasm_bindgen`'s inner workings.

Comment: @kmdreko do the exported items not have any sort of scoping? I'm using the type like this in js: `import {Error as MyError} from "myModule";`. Would that then be an error I've never defined but was defined and exported by a create I'm using?

Comment: @kmdreko So basically I don't what to shadow to the global JS Error struct, I want to create my own, scoped error struct, just like in javascript modules.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
struct Error {}
```

...means that you want your own `struct Error` to be treated as WASM-binding to the [JavaScript `Error` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error). Since `console_error_panic_hook` needs to bind to JavaScript `Error` too, this generates a conflict - with multiple bindings, it's unclear what struct should be created in Rust, when JavaScript passes its `Error` to WASM function.

Comment: That's not really what I indended to do, I'm importing the error in JS in the following way: `import {Error as MyError} from "./myModule";`